# Creating Loop to replace text in page layout in multiple MXDs instead of one MXD at a time?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.6

I found some code on a website that will perform a search and replace on page layout text elements. Currently you can only do it one MXD at a time. I was hoping to change the code so I can do a search and replace on a folder with a bunch of MXDs in it.

The script is below. I know I need  a loop, just not sure how to do it; never programmed before.

```
import arcpy, string, os 

#Read input parameters from script tool
Path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
oldText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
newText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
case = arcpy.GetParameter(3)
exact = arcpy.GetParameter(4)
outputMXD = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)

try:
    #Referent the map document
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)         

    #Find all page layout text elements
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):     
        if exact:
            if case:
                if oldText == elm.text:
                    elmText = elm.text.replace(oldText, newText)
                    elm.text = elmText
            else:
                if oldText.upper() == elm.text.upper():
                    elmText = elm.text.upper().replace(oldText, newText)
                    elm.text = elmText   
        else:
            if case:
                if oldText in elm.text:
                    elmText = elm.text.replace(oldText, newText)
                    elm.text = elmText
            else:
                if oldText.upper() in elm.text.upper():
                    elmText = elm.text.upper().replace(oldText, newText)
                    elm.text = elmText                  
    mxd.saveACopy(outputMXD)

    del mxd

except Exception, e:
    import traceback
    map(arcpy.AddError, traceback.format_exc().split("\n"))
    arcpy.AddError(str(e))
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Answer (score 6):

The [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/)  help topic has an example of how to loop through .mxd's in a folder (as well as other useful arcpy examples) but my preference for how to do this would be to use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html). Something like this:

```
import glob
mxdList = glob.glob('*.mxd')
for mxd in mxdList:
    <put everything from your try/except block here>
```

This assumes your script runs from the folder where you have all your .mxd's. You could also organize this a bit better with a few functions but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#This script will search through all mxds in a folder
#and will search and replace multi-line text string within each mxd and
#print out a new pdf

#Notes:
#The "Old text" must match exactly to the existing text to be
#replaced, with no "white space" before or after the text. Otherwise, the script will not #work. Best approach is to copy the text from the mxd(s) to be edited and paste it to the #script where "old text" variable is located.

#For multi-line text, be sure to include the "\r\n" string.
import arcpy
import os
import glob

folder = ws = "S:\\GIS\\xtemp"

#Enter all EXACT cases of text to change below- remember to include "\r\n" where next #line is needed:

oldtext = "Corte Madera Creek Flood Risk Management\r\nCorte Madera, Marin County, CA"
newtext = "Corte Madera Creek Flood Risk Management Project\r\nMarin County, CA"

#This is only used to see how the text will be written out in the final output:
print "old text:" + oldtext
print "newtext:" + newtext

print "Searching mxds in:" + folder

#This script part will allow a search of all mxds in the folder:
mxd = arcpy.mapping
mxds = glob.glob(folder + '\\' + '*.mxd')
arcpy.gp.overwriteOutput = True

for mxdFile in mxds:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdFile)
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.text == oldtext:
            elm.text = newtext
    mxd.save()
    del mxd       
print "Text replacement complete - printing new pdfs to:" + folder

#This script part will print the final pdfs after changes have been made:
Workspace = ws
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd_path = os.path.join(Workspace,file)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
    outpdf = file + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,outpdf)
    mxd.save()
print "Finished! New pdfs printed to:" + folder
```